# Need a solution for PHP header and relative links

Tags: php, wordpress

I think this should be a fairly simple question for anyone who knows PHP. I am more of a designer and still in the process of learning PHP.

I have a site I built which includes a PHP header and footer include. In the header file (which is used by ALL pages in the site) I have links to CSS files, JavaScript files, etc.

Right now I am using this solution for the links and includes in the header...

```
http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/css/style.css
```

The issue with that is that some of the pages in the site are SSL pages and need to use a HTTPS prefix, not HTTP. That being said, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to link to CSS files, JavaScripts, images, etc. within the header file other than what I'm currently using?

Comment: You're best bet is to completely remove the domain from the url. I.e. the link should be `/css/style.css` This tells the browser to look at the current domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

If that won't work for you, write a PHP function.

```
function base_url()
{
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS'])
        return "https://mysite.com";
    else
        return "http://mysite.com";
}
```

and in your html code.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/ssl_stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a [relative protocol](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/): `//<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/css/style.css`